# How to jump into python code in c++ call through GDB debugger?

Tags: python, c++, gdb

I have a C++ project which was written by others, which calls python code at the end of the execution.

In the C++ initializer, it defines a pHandle:

```
pHandle_ = PyObject_CallObject(pLoad_, NULL);
PyGILState_Release(gstate);
```

Then it calls python code this way:

```
PyObject *pyValue = PyObject_CallObject(pProcess_, pArgs);
```

pProcess_ and pArgs are created earlier. The python code's file name is 'runLogic.py' and the function executed in runLogic.py is 'process()'.

Is there a way to break into the python's process() function while I debug in c++ through GDB?  In C++ code, I can step through until the line above, copied again below:
PyObject *pyValue = PyObject_CallObject(pProcess_, pArgs);

Then I don't  know how to jump into the  Python's function.

Is there a way to do that? I want to trace the full logic of the  code, in addition to C++'s code.

Answer (score 0):

> Then I don't know how to jump into the Python's function.

Presumably you want to now step through Python code.

GDB doesn't know how to do that, but `pdb` can.

Assuming you can modify `runLogic.py`, add `import pdb` to the top of the file, and `pdb.set_trace()` in the `process()` function.

This will let you step through Python code. If you have breakpoints in `C++`, and `Python` code calls back into `C++`, these breakpoints will still be active, you should be able to debug both `C++` and `Python`.

Comment: So you mean I add 'import pdb' in runLogic.py, and add 'pdb.set_trace()' in runLogic's process() function. Then In C++, how to set the breakpoint for the runLogic function?

Comment: My debugging starts from c++ code, not python, because the logic starts in c++. It is that case that C++ calls python code, not the other way!

Comment: @marlon "My debugging starts from c++ code" -- it doesn't matter. You will have two separate debuggers, GDB for the C++ side and pdb for the Python side. Each can have its own breakpoints, and step through its own code.